# Exposing Spring services as SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring, soap

I have a quite extensive Spring 3.0 service architecture (the typical architecture; a bunch of model objects and a bunch of services that do stuff with these objects). I would like expose some of these services as SOAP web services.

We have developed SOAP web services before, but these have always been relatively simple and dedicated, and we have always used Axis 2. I found Axis 2 a bit heavy on the dependency and implementation side, and I'm a bit worried that this will bloat my current project something awful.

I have looked around and apparently using Apache CXF this would seem quite easy. So I'm looking for some advice on this. Does anyone have any practical experience with this? Pros and cons?

Comment: What sort of web service development style do you want? "code-first", or "schema-first"?

Comment: Preferably code first, since this code already exists (I already have the Spring services, I just want to expose some of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using spring with CXF for soap services and it goes very smooth. Following the CXF tutorial makes it straightforward to use by simply using the `jaxws` xml namespace.

Comment: I have found a good example on this: http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/developing-a-simple-soap-webservice-using-spring-301-and-apache-cxf-226

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tested any other webservice frameworks - always been going with CXF and am quite happy with that.

If you're using Netbeans (even if not, it's still useful I'd say), check out this tutorial: http://sites.google.com/site/apachecxfnetbeans/loanproc

Just skip the first few paragraphs (Database integration, testing etc. etc. .. all of which you should already have knowledge about).
The CXF integration in Netbeans is useful for writing fast clients using the built-in netbeans functionalities.

cheers